# How to find dy/dx by logarithmic differentiation

Tags: derivatives

The question says find dy/dx by logarithmic differentiation
2
Definite integral.   E^-1/x divided by x^2 dx
1

Answer choices are

A 1-sqrt(e)/e

B 1-e

C sqrt(e)-1/e

D sqrt(e)-e/e

E sqrt(e)

If you could provide an explanation and/or show steps it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm confused about the "2" between "differentiation" and "Definite".  And the "1" after "dx".  This doesn't quite makes sense.... please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Let me outline the general procedure of logarithmic differentiation.
$$y=f(x)\\
\implies \dfrac{y^\prime}{y}=\dfrac{d}{dx}\ln(f(x))\\
\implies y^\prime=f(x)\times \dfrac{d}{dx}\ln(f(x))$$
You need to also use the fundamental theorem of calculus in this problem.